# knockout-postbox syncwith not working with observable arrays

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-postbox

I have the below view models.  in view model one I also have some code that adds records to accountList.  when I then try to use accountList in viewmodel two, it's always empty.  shouldn't the syncWith keep those two observableArrays in sync?

ViewModel one

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./eligible.html', 'kendo'
    , 'toastr'
    , 'Scripts/App/models/m_accountslist'
    , 'Scripts/App/constants/cont'
    , 'postbox'
], function (ko, eligible, k, toastr, model, cont) {

    function eligibleViewModel(params) {

        var self = this;

        self.accountList = ko.observableArray().syncWith("accountList", true,false)

        return self;
    }


    return { viewModel: eligibleViewModel, template: eligible }
})
```

View Model Two

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./offermodal.html'
    , 'toastr'
    , 'Scripts/App/models/m_accountslist'
    , 'komapping'
    , 'Scripts/App/constants/cont'
    , 'postbox'], function (ko, offermodal, toastr, model, komapping,cont) {

        var offermodalViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.accountList = ko.observableArray().syncWith("accountList",true,false)

        return self;
    }
    return { viewModel: offermodalViewModel, template: offermodal }
});
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle, here is [one](http://fiddle.jshell.net/AnishPatelUk/8jvL1kgs/) using requirejs if it helps. Also have you tried initializing `accountList` with an array? i.e. `self.accountList = ko.observableArray([]).syncWith("accountList", true, false);`

Comment: I'll try to create a fiddle for it.  when I initialize the array I still don't get the sync to work

Comment: Hopefully you can get a fiddle that shows your issue. Here is a basic one that shows the syncing: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rd5aLsz4/